# Setting up the dark Greybird theme on Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: xfce, theme, xubuntu, gtk3

I have read that Xubuntu 18.04 has a [dark theme](https://wiki.xubuntu.org/releases/18.04/release-notes), but I could not find it anywhere. I have manually upgraded to the newest version from 16.04. Perhaps this is the reason why I could not find it, or do I need an extra tool?

Comment: what command did you used in upgrading to the newest version?

Comment: I ran `sudo do-release-update -d`

Answer (score 0):

## Official solution

Create a `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` file with the following content.

```
[Settings]
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=true
```

Logout for these settings to take effect.

`gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme` and other settings are [documented here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSettings.html#GtkSettings--gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme).

## Better solution

The official solution is far from perfect with XFCE. Stay away from it and rather add the following two files to your system.

This will result in a dark XFCE `Applications Menu` as well as dark menu panes in all other GTK2/3 applications, in line with the standard Xubuntu LTS panel colours.

Other GTK2/3 user interface surfaces remain Greybird grey. Obviously, the hexadecimal RGB colour definitions can be changed as one likes.

**1)** Add a hidden `.gtkrc-2.0` file to your `$HOME` director with the following contents:

```
style "gtk-theme-config-menu" {
    base[NORMAL] = "#2e3436"
    bg[NORMAL] = "#2e3436"
    bg[ACTIVE] = "#2e3436"
    bg[INSENSITIVE] = "#2e3436"
    text[NORMAL] = "#d3d7cf"
    fg[NORMAL] = "#d3d7cf"
}

widget_class"*<GtkMenu>*"style"gtk-theme-config-menu"
```

**2)** Add a file named `gtk.css` to the `~/.config/gtk-3.0/` directory with below content. The `panel` configuration is commented out, but is kept here for reference.

```
/* Custom styles */

/* select-on */
@define-color selected_bg_color #398ee7;
@define-color selected_fg_color #fff;
@define-color theme_selected_bg_color @selected_bg_color;
@define-color theme_selected_fg_color @selected_fg_color;
/* select-on */

/* panel-off
@define-color panel_bg_color #2e3436;
@define-color panel_fg_color #ffffff;

PanelWidget,
PanelApplet,
PanelToplevel,
PanelSeparator,
PanelApplet > GtkMenuBar.menubar,
PanelApplet > GtkMenuBar.menubar.menuitem,
PanelApplet > menubar,
PanelApplet > menubar.menuitem,
PanelApplet > menubar menuitem,
PanelMenuBar.menubar,
PanelMenuBar.menubar.menuitem,
PanelMenuBar.menubar menuitem,
PanelAppletFrame,
UnityPanelWidget,
.gnome-panel-menu-bar,
.unity-panel,
.xfce4-panel,
.xfce4-panel.background {
    background-color: @panel_bg_color;
    background-image: -gtk-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(shade(@panel_bg_color,1.2)),to(shade(@panel_bg_color,0.8)));
    color: @panel_fg_color;
}

.unity-panel.menuitem,
.unity-panel .menuitem,
.unity-panel menuitem {
    color: @panel_fg_color;
}

.unity-panel.menubar.menuitem:hover,
.unity-panel.menubar .menuitem *:hover,
.unity-panel.menubar menuitem *:hover {
    border-color: shade(@panel_bg_color, 0.7);
    border-image: none;
    background-color: shade(@panel_bg_color, 0.97);
    background-image: -gtk-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(shade(@panel_bg_color, 0.97)),to(shade(@panel_bg_color, 0.82)));
    color: @panel_fg_color;
}

PanelApplet .button,
PanelApplet button,
.xfce4-panel .button,
.xfce4-panel button {
    border-color: transparent;
    border-image: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: @panel_fg_color;
    box-shadow: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    -unico-inner-stroke-width: 0;
}

PanelApplet .button:active,
PanelApplet button:active,
.xfce4-panel .button:active,
.xfce4-panel button:active {
    border-color: shade(@panel_bg_color,0.8);
    border-image: none;
    background-color: shade(shade(@panel_bg_color,1.02),0.9);
    background-image: -gtk-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(shade(shade(@panel_bg_color,1.02),0.9)),to(shade(shade(@panel_bg_color,1.02),0.95)));
    color: @panel_fg_color;
    box-shadow: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    -unico-inner-stroke-width: 0;
}

PanelApplet .button:prelight,
PanelApplet button:prelight,
.xfce4-panel .button:hover,
.xfce4-panel button:hover {
    border-color: transparent;
    border-image: none;
    background-color: shade(@panel_bg_color,1.2);
    background-image: -gtk-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(shade(@panel_bg_color,1.2)),to(shade(@panel_bg_color,1.0)));
    color: @panel_fg_color;
    box-shadow: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    -unico-inner-stroke-width: 0;
}

PanelApplet .button:active:prelight,
PanelApplet button:active:prelight,
.xfce4-panel .button:active:hover,
.xfce4-panel button:active:hover {
    border-color: shade(@panel_bg_color,0.8);
    border-image: none;
    background-color: shade(shade(@panel_bg_color,1.02),1.0);
    background-image: -gtk-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(shade(shade(@panel_bg_color,1.02),1.0)),to(shade(shade(@panel_bg_color,1.02),1.05)));
    color: @panel_fg_color;
    box-shadow: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    -unico-inner-stroke-width: 0;
}

WnckPager,
WnckTasklist {
    background-color: @panel_bg_color;
}

panel-off */

/* menu-on */
@define-color menu_bg_color #2e3436;
@define-color menu_fg_color #d3d7cf;

GtkTreeMenu.menu,
GtkMenuToolButton.menu,
GtkComboBox .menu,
GtkComboBox menu {
    background-color: @menu_bg_color;
    background-image: none;
}

.primary-toolbar .button .menu,
.primary-toolbar button menu,
.toolbar .menu,
toolbar menu,
.toolbar .primary-toolbar .menu,
toolbar .primary-toolbar menu,
.menu,
menu,
#toolbar-popup {
    border-style: none;
    background-image: none;
    background-color: @menu_bg_color;
    background-image: none;
    color: @menu_fg_color;
    box-shadow: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    -unico-inner-stroke-width: 0;
}

.menu.button:hover,
menu.button:hover,
.menu.button:active,
menu.button:active,
.menu.button:active:insensitive,
menu.button:active:insensitive,
.menu.button:insensitive,
menu.button:insensitive,
.menu.button,
menu.button {
    background-color: @menu_bg_color;
    background-image: none;
}

GtkTreeMenu .menuitem *,
GtkTreeMenu menuitem * {
    color: @menu_fg_color;
}

.menuitem,
menuitem,
.menu .menuitem,
menu menuitem {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
}

.menu .menuitem:active,
menu menuitem:active,
.menu .menuitem:hover,
menu menuitem:hover {
    background-color: @theme_selected_bg_color;
    background-image: none;
}

.menuitem.check,
menuitem.check,
.menuitem.radio,
menuitem.radio,
.menuitem.check:hover,
menuitem.check:hover,
.menuitem.radio:hover,
menuitem.radio:hover,
.menuitem.check:active,
menuitem.check:active,
.menuitem.radio:active,
menuitem.radio:active {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
}

.menu .menuitem:insensitive,
menu menuitem:insensitive,
.menu .menuitem *:insensitive,
menu menuitem *:insensitive {
    color: mix(@menu_fg_color,@menu_bg_color,0.5);
}

.menuitem.arrow,
menuitem.arrow {
    color: alpha(@menu_fg_color, 0.6);
}

.menuitem .entry,
menuitem entry {
    border-color: shade(@menu_bg_color,0.7);
    border-image: none;
    background-color: @menu_bg_color;
    background-image: none;
    color: @menu_fg_color;
}

.menuitem .accelerator,
menuitem accelerator {
    color: alpha(@menu_fg_color,0.6);
}

.menuitem .accelerator:insensitive,
menuitem accelerator:insensitive {
    color: alpha(mix(@menu_fg_color,@menu_bg_color,0.5),0.6);
    text-shadow: none;
}

.menuitem.separator,
menuitem.separator {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    color: shade(@menu_bg_color, 0.9);
}

.menuitem GtkCalendar,
menuitem calendar,
.menuitem GtkCalendar.button,
menuitem calendar.button,
.menuitem GtkCalendar.header,
menuitem calendar.header,
.menuitem GtkCalendar.view,
menuitem calendar.view {
    border-color: shade(@menu_bg_color,0.8);
    border-image: none;
    background-color: @menu_bg_color;
    background-image: none;
    color: @menu_fg_color;
}

.menuitem GtkCalendar:inconsistent,
menuitem calendar:inconsistent {
    color: mix(@menu_fg_color,@menu_bg_color,0.5);
}

/* menu-on */

/* End custom styles */
```

**3) Log out** for these changes to take effect.